# Using the Extended DisMax query parser in Blacklight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, blacklight

When running Solr queries from [Blacklight](http://projectblacklight.org/) the query parser being used is the [DisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) query parser. However, the query parser configured in my `solrconfig.xml` file is the [EDisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) parser. For some reason, Blacklight sends `deftype=dismax` in the request to Solr and so overrides the desired `deftype=edismax` value as it is defined in Solr's configuration.

How do I stop Blacklight from overriding the `deftype` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Blacklight's Advanced Search gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/blacklight_advanced_search)? The dismax parser is hard coded in the `tree.rb` file under `lib/parsing_nesting` in the Advanced Search gem. If you want to use the edismax parser you have to create a new "parsing_nesting" directory under the "lib" directory. Copy the `tree.rb` file to the "parsing_nesting" directory you have created. The easy (but kind of ugly) solution would be to replace all the "dismax" with "edismax" in the file. A better, but harder, solution would be to read the whole file thoroughly and change some function signatures so that they don't require the "force_deftype" parameter. Start with removing the `:force_deftype => "dismax"` from the `build_nested_query` function and see where this leads you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the use of the dismax parser is default set in the Blacklight code. However, you can override it by modifying your /app/contollers/catalog_controller.rb file and adding the defType setting to the `config.default_solr_params` variable. The default that comes with Blacklight would look like the following after this modification:

```
    config.default_solr_params = { 
      :qt => 'search',
      :rows => 10,
      :defType => 'edismax' 
    }
```